# Angular Nested Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the requirement of showing the data in angular grid with grouping the rows if it found row key same :

```
for e.g.
          {
               "No": 1,
               "RMA": "DEH30002",
               "Batch": "Batch",
           },
           {
               "No": 2,
               "RMA": "DEH30002",
               "Batch": "Batch",
           },
           {
               "No": 3,
               "RMA": "DEH30003",
               "Batch": "Batch",
           }
```

for the above data of angular grid,
I want the grouping on first two row because their RMA no. is same, but don't want third in any group because it's RMA is unique.

i.e.  first row should have expandable row having both same RMA in a group and second row shows a regular row without any expandable sign on it.

Pls. guide how to implement this using angualr.
FYI. the data comes from web api. thanks!

Comment: You can use ui.grid. Please check an example here. http://codepen.io/kenobi883/pen/gPbjEQ

Comment: Sagar in your example i don't want first row to be grouped because it has single child row in it